# Angular 2 : Selector tags won't load

Tags: angular

I am trying out Angular 2 and following a book, now when i create a new component using quickstart with following code

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<h1>Hello</h1>'
})
export Class MyComponent{

}
```

file named `my-component-component.ts`and imported my component into app.component.ts, but when i add my selector `<my-component></my-component>`, the page won't load. I tried removing it and it works fine. 
Where am I making mistake?
Following is the code i am adding in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1><my-component></my-component>'
    directive: [MyComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Edit : The error in console says

> (index):18 Error: (SystemJS) Class is not defined

and he file it is referring to is index for Angular Quickstart (can be found on git)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any errors being shown in the console. Also, the `angularjs` tag is for Angular 1.x questions; the `angular2` tag is the one you want. Lastly, the letter i, when used to refer to yourself, should be capitalized.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thnx i did that.

Comment: what version of angular are you using? and assuming you are using an NgModule component please post that as well.

Comment: @Bean0341 i downloaded nodejs from node website and angular from [quickstart] (https://angular.io/) , not using NgModel as when i do npm start. it loads up localhost with default page, i am adding `<my-component>` to the page as described above.

Comment: Ok I misspoke, add your systemjs and your app.module component

Comment: @Bean0341 how, i am new at this so i need to where.

Comment: Those should be files already in your project. I want you to add them to the question so I can view them, if you do not have these files in your project then you need to go back through the tutorial :) and to reduce confusion I will add the full names of the files. should be `systemjs.config.js` and `app.module.ts `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127307/discussion-between-nofel-and-bean0341).

Answer (score 0):

your issue is in you app.module.ts file you not only need to add `MyComponent` to your declarations, you also need to add the import as well. your app.module should look like the following...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component'; <----Here

@NgModule({ 
imports: [ BrowserModule ], 
declarations: [ AppComponent, MyComponent ], <-----and Here
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ] 
}) 

export class AppModule { }
```

also in your app component remove the following line of code....

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1><my-component></my-component>'

    directive: [MyComponent]    ***<-----REMOVE THIS LINE!***
})
 export class AppComponent { }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add MyComponent to module declarations.

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent, 
        MyComponent // <-- added here
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```